# Custom Android Utility Class

Tags: java, android

I was wondering if you can point out a good Android Utility class containing static methods for various, commonly used Android and/or Java functions (ex. checking network availability)?

Comment: There are no common class...put your task which you want  in static method..and call `YourUtilityClassName.staticmethodName();`

Comment: @Medo Please collect all methods in a class and post here

Comment: @ShahzadImam I was hoping someone did all the collecting already and is willing to share it :)

Comment: Yeah u can start with that .U will get many one over here

Comment: @Medo "Commonly used" is far more than you appear to think (many thousands). Here is a sample http://java-source.net/

Comment: check the right way to declare utility classes http://stackoverflow.com/a/31315263/3496570

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not exactly you required but can found few here .......

https://github.com/kaeppler/droid-fu/tree/master/src/main/java/com/github/droidfu/support

http://droid4me.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/droid4me/src/com/smartnsoft/droid4me/

Android helper/utility class library

you will get utility like writeToFile, isNullOrEmpty  and other AnimationUtils AppUtils LayoutUtils ......

http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?page_id=217

Answer (score 0):

> was wondering if you can point out a good Android Utility class
>   containing static methods for various, commonly used Android and/or
>   Java functions

Google is your friend :) .You can collect/write methods  + make them static + add to utility class.

**For Checking Network Connectivity.**

```
 ConnectivityManager connectivityManager=ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    if (connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).isConnected()
                    || connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).isConnected())
            {
                //Connected to internet

    }
 else
 {
  //Not Connected to internet
 }
```