# Utility Class - What is the correct approach?

Tags: java, class

What is the correct approach for a utility class having all methods with public static.
Should I use final class or abstract class?
Please give suggestion.
As for example:

```
public final class A{ 
    public static void method(){
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

OR

```
public abstract class A{
    public static void method(){
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`abstract` has its own purpose. If you want some of the class functionality implemented by other classes (`override`) then you use abstract.

If it is just utility class, but you don't want other classes subclass it, then I would go with `final` class. If utility class has just `static` methods, any way you can't override them, so it doesn't make difference to have them in `non-final` class also.

Comment: You should also add a private, no-args constructor, so that no other code tries to instiate the class.

Comment: is it a valid question? I m new in stack overfow..if i ask an invalid question, please help.

Answer (score 10):

> Best approach for creating Utility classes. If you don't want other classes to inherit it.

```
//final, because it's not supposed to be subclassed
public final class AlertUtils 
{ 

// private constructor to avoid unnecessary instantiation of the class
    private AlertUtils() {
    }

  public static ..(){}//other methods
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`final` here makes better sense than `abstract`. By marking the class as `final`, you forbid the extending the class. On the other hand marking the class as `abstract` is kind of opposite, because abstract class without subclasses doesn't make much sense. So it is expected to be extended.

Comment: Yeah that is true, but I wouldn't say it is the main purpose. If one creates an abstract class it is expected it will be extended by other class or instantiated as anonymous class with all abstract method overriden.

Answer (score 3):

Make the class final and add a private constructor. (This is what classes like `java.lang.Math` use)

```
public final class A { 
    private A() {}

    public static void method() {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want other classes to use the functionality of this class then make it **abstract** else make it **Final**

Answer (score 1):

These are some guidelines I've found:

- All methods must be public static, so that they cannot be overridden.
- Constructor must be private, so it'll prevent instantiation.
- Final keyword for the class prevents sub-classing.
- Class should not have any non-final or non-static class fields.

As you've asked, the class name cannot be abstract (not advisable) -> Which means you are planning to implement it in another class. If you want to prevent sub-classing, use final for the class name; If you want to prevent instantiation, use a private constructor.