# Best way to make class as util?

Tags: java, oop, static, static-methods, final

I have class which must work as util . I do not need its instance , all what it contains are `static` members and `static` functions . So What's best way to do that ? Make it `final` with `private` constructor as `Math` class in java  or just make its constructor `private` without making it `final` ?

Comment: Eh, whatever, it doesn't much matter.  If the constructor's private it can't be subclassed anyway.

Comment: if its not final, but has a private ctor, it can still be sub-classed by an inner static class. Having it be both final and a private ctor makes it easier for a reader to tell its purpose, so I would do that.

Comment: somewhat a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/309553/should-helper-utility-classes-be-abstract  and   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12538487/utility-class-what-is-the-correct-approach   and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25223553/how-can-i-create-an-utility-class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`private` constructor is enough, no need to mark the class `final`, by having the private constructor we can't subclass it

If you make the constructor `private` you can still access it using `reflection`.

Better approach is throw `AssertionError`

```
public class Util {    
    private Util() {
        throw new AssertionError("Can't instantiate");
    }
    // static methods
}
```

Below code is to instantiate private constructor

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Constructor<Util> utilC = Util.class.getDeclaredConstructor();
            utilC.setAccessible(true);
            Util u = utilC.newInstance(); // instance           
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // exception handling
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for the util class,you no need provide constructor.because this functions are static,you can use like this: Util.a()

Comment: I'm pretty sure he knows the benefits of static methods. He's wondering if he should make the class abstract or final or non-final with private constructor. He's basically asking which one is considered the best practice.

Comment: thanks.in my opinion，if the class only provide static methods ，use private constructor is better